# Display PDF from Oracle Database in browser from ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, pdf

I have a BLOB field containing a PDF document.  I want to retrieve that BLOB and display the PDF in a new tab or window.  I am already retrieving the BLOB but am not able to display it.  I am using C# and ASP.net 2010.  So far, the code I have is this:

```
byte[] blobBuffer = getPDFBlob(selectedOfferId);

if (blobBuffer != null)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    //Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
    Response.BinaryWrite(blobBuffer);
    Response.End();
}
```

`getPDFBlob` is a routine that goes into the database and retrieves the contents of the BLOB field.  What am I missing?

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error? Why are you not able to display it?

Comment: The code executes, but nothing happens...no error, no nothing.

Comment: And you don't get the PDF opened? What happens in the browser?

Comment: why do you have the Response.AddHeader line commented out?

Comment: These lines were not working, so I commented them out to see if that would help, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Response.Clear();` before setting `ContentType` etc.

Also try calling `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");` before calling `BinaryWrite`.

**UPDATE - as per comments:**

Depending on what you want to achieve (download versus display in the browser) you can alternatively try calling `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");` before calling `BinaryWrite`.

**UPDATE 2:**

Another point you should check is the content of `blobBuffer` - write it to a local file and see whether it is actually a valid PDF...

**UPDATE 3:**

After calling `BinaryWrite` and before calling `End` try calling `Response.Flush();`.

Comment: attachment will force a download, i think he wants to display in window.

Comment: filename=test.pdf??  My file does not have a name when it is read from the Database.  I want to open the contents in a new tab or new window with the option of printing or saving if needed, but the main function is to display.

Comment: @D.Bermudez I know that the BLOB does not have a filename BUT most browsers expect some filename... please try the above code...

Comment: @D.Bermudez then you need to give much more details... how are you testing this ? did you check what I wrote in UPDATE 2 above ?

Comment: Yes I did the above code in the UPDATES.  I am testing this from visual studio...using Chrome and IE 9.

Comment: @D.Bermudez I can't help you without some details... the code above works absolutely fine here...

Comment: I will save the BLOB content I am getting from the database into a physical file to confirm that the contents are being read properly.  Assuming the file is correct, what would be the next step??

Comment: @D.Bermudez place the file as a static pdf in some IIS folder and access it from the browser and see what happens...

Comment: I was able to create a physical PDF file from the blob content by changing the code and telling it to create the file on my desktop, but when I use the original code and the updated code above, there is no display or download in the browser.  Could this be a setting within the browser?  In Chrome or Internet Explorer 9??

Comment: @D.Bermudez it can be setting in the browser and/or security settings etc.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=mypdf.pdf");
```

Comment: filename=mypdf.pdf?? My file does not have a name when it is read from the Database. I want to open the contents in a new tab or new window with the option of printing or saving if needed, but the main function is to display.

Comment: you can put any name you like!

Comment: Did that, but still it doesn't work...don't know what's going on